# How to make menu to slide right on click using HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates, css-animations

I have an HTML page in which there is an side menu bar that displays a list of dashboards which is done using Django. 
i want this menu(left-side menu) to show only a part of it when logged in and show fully after clicking on it.

The code for the html looks like this:

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li><span style="color:blue; font-weight:bold;">Dashboards</span></li>     
  {% for Dashboard in dashboards %}
<li><a href="{{ Dashboard.d_url }}" target="iframe_a">{{ Dashboard.d_name }}</a></li>
           {% endfor %}
          </ul>
          
        </div>
```

since i am not familiar with jquery and all i want to know if there are any ways which works with only css and javascript to do this.
when i open my html file it looks like this
[image]
after clicking on icon
[image]

Comment: Can you show the html output rather then template code and the css you have so far. Also, a jsfiddle would be useful and a more detailed description of what you mean by "slide to right on click"

Comment: i cannot add snapshot here coz of reputations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is not very clear what you are trying to do, but i understand that is something like  `transition: left 1s;` or  `transition: transform 1s`; and when you press your button toggles a class for changing `left` or `transform: translateX(value);` styles like [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ij5hIK?p=preview)

But also you need to understand if that menu will push your other content or not.

That's a basic transition and a **basic Layout** i'm not sure if it fits on your requirements.
Also for IE9 and older browsers support you might want to check animations using jQuery or [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/show/)

Comment: i am looking for exactly what you posted as answer. but its not working for me and when i copy paste my code in plunker and run its working there.

Comment: Please update a plunk otherwise we can't know what are you trying to do. And please remove all the code that is not necessary for your problem

Comment: can u see my updated code where i have mentioned only the div which is acting as side bar here. And i need this side bar to move in and out on click

Comment: may be because i am using django along with html its not working. is it??

Comment: Sorry but you are not been clear about what you need to do, you only leave is a html and said that you need to slide a menu. I only can  understand that you need to add the effect on the _.sidebar_ element, in which case the example that i already wrote should work fine, using _position: absolute, left: 0;_ and fixed _width_ for the show state and use a _transform: translateX(-100%);_ for the hidden state

Comment: yea i have checked your example. i need  exactly same as u have done. but its not working for me when i open html through server.can you tel me what else i should post along with this html

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer i had some path issues. now its resolved.

Comment: hii matho its working but my div is not sliding as in your example its just hiding and showing back. is there any issue

Comment: [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8N2XEl?p=preview) is the plnkr with the fix, first of all you are not compiling the code in the plnker example, so is no useful to have imports like `src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"` it doesn't work in HTML the javascript and the CSS files weren't even loaded. Then your issue is that you are directly executing the code that searchs for the Menu Bttn and binds a function, but you have to do: `$( document ).ready(Fn...); `[$( document ).ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: thanks for your patience .Still div with id "mobile-menu" in your example. its not hiding fully when i click.

Comment: i have updated my question with images may be it will be clarity now. can u please take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

check out this code of javascript which does required

```js
$("#menu-button").bind( "click", function() {
  $('#mobile-menu').toggleClass('open');
  $('#overlay').show(0);

});

$("#overlay").bind( "click", function() {
  $('#mobile-menu').removeClass('open');
  $('#overlay').hide(0);
  //basically so that clicking outside closes the menu; but on mobile I think it's immediately undoing the add class above
});


$('#menu-button').click(function(){
   $(this).find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-right glyphicon-chevron-left')
});
```